# Writing to SQL Server datetime datatype from Scala/Spark

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, databricks

I'm attempting to bulk insert into SQL Server table from a databricks notebook using a similar method as this:

[Bulk copy to Azure SQL Database or SQL Server](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases-azure.html#id7)

This works fine, until I attempt to write to a column of datatype datetime. The table I'm attempting to write to has this schema:

```
create table raw.HubDrg_TEST
(
  DrgKey varchar(64) not null,
  LoadDate datetime,
  LoadProcess varchar(255),
  RecordSource varchar(255),
  DrgCode varchar(255)
 )
```

My Scala code is as follows:

```
//Get dataset for data in staging table
var stagedData: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall)
  .option("tempDir", tempDir)
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("query", "select distinct CodeID as DrgCode, getdate() as LoadDate from StageMeditech.livendb_dbo_DAbsDrgs").load() 

//Get dataset for data in existing Hub
val existingHub: DataFrame = spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
  .option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall)
  .option("tempDir", tempDir)
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("query", "Select DrgKey as ExistingDrgKey from raw.HubDrg_TEST")
  .load()

val sha_256 = udf((s: String) => { String.format("%032x", new BigInteger(1, MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(s.getBytes("UTF-8")))) })

//Add additional columns
stagedData = stagedData.withColumn("DrgKey",sha_256(col("DrgCode"))).withColumn("LoadProcess",lit("TestLoadProcess"))
                                   .withColumn("RecordSource",lit("TestRecordSource"))
//Join and filter out existing hub records
val dff = stagedData.join(existingHub, col("DrgKey")===col("ExistingDrgKey"), "left_outer").filter(existingHub.col("ExistingDrgKey").isNull).drop("ExistingDrgKey") 

//Bulk insert
val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map( 
"url" -> dwServer, 
"databaseName" -> dwDatabase, 
"user" -> dwUser, 
"password" -> dwPass, 
"dbTable" -> "raw.HubDrg_TEST", 
"bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "2000", 
"bulkCopyTableLock" -> "false", 
"bulkCopyTimeout" -> "0" 
)) 

dff.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the datetime value I'm selecting as `getdate() as LoadDate` is giving me this error when attempting to insert into the above mentioned table: `SqlNativeBufferBufferBulkCopy.WriteTdsDataToServer, error in OdbcDone: SqlState: 42000, NativeError: 4816, 'Error calling: bcp_done(this->GetHdbc()) | SQL Error Info: SrvrMsgState: 1, SrvrSeverity: 16,  Error <1>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column type from bcp client for colid 2. | Error calling: pConn->Done() | state: FFFF, number: 58673, active connections: 9', Connection String: Driver={pdwodbc17e};app=TypeC01-DmsNativeWriter:DB66\mpdwsvc (13056)-ODBC;trusted_connection=yes;autotranslate=no;server=\\.\pipe\DB.66-a313018f1e5b\sql\query;database=Distribution_15`

Even when attempting to not use a datetime value from the SQL Server query and changing the LoadDate value to: `withColumn("LoadDate",current_timestamp())` ,attempting to use the [current_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/index.html#current_timestamp) builtin function in spark, it still doesn't work.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798914/scala-sql-server-how-to-insert-the-current-timestamp-as-datetime-in-sql-serve) stackoverflow article, which is a similar question, but it still did not answer the question. Does anyone have a good example on how to insert into an SQL Server table with a [datetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) datatype using the `com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.bulkcopy._` library?

Here is a sample of the data from doing a `dff.show()`

```
    +-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+----------------+
    |DrgCode|            LoadDate|              DrgKey|    LoadProcess|    RecordSource|
    +-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+----------------+
    |    390|2019-07-02 09:05:...|48a1a756f2d83f1dc...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |     18|2019-07-02 09:05:...|4ec9599fc203d176a...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    481|2019-07-02 09:05:...|51d089cdaf0c968c9...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    460|2019-07-02 09:05:...|841a05fd378a2c067...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    838|2019-07-02 09:05:...|cef5838d118dccd9d...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |     61|2019-07-02 09:05:...|d029fa3a95e174a19...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    807|2019-07-02 09:05:...|fce86e339dc3131c4...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |     44|2019-07-02 09:05:...|71ee45a3c0db9a986...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    267|2019-07-02 09:05:...|8acc23987b8960d83...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    222|2019-07-02 09:05:...|9b871512327c09ce9...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    934|2019-07-02 09:05:...|a8443b1426652157e...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    677|2019-07-02 09:05:...|2782526eaa0c5c254...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    701|2019-07-02 09:05:...|290a0b92873bdf4e4...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    441|2019-07-02 09:05:...|2dfe70c43208f52b9...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    439|2019-07-02 09:05:...|50a010ce24d089605...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    883|2019-07-02 09:05:...|3055e0d8130c7a197...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    947|2019-07-02 09:05:...|4d0198f4905a08812...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    369|2019-07-02 09:05:...|5f193b350c8aba488...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |     21|2019-07-02 09:05:...|6f4b6612125fb3a0d...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    |    503|2019-07-02 09:05:...|7182dd431b5c8833e...|TestLoadProcess|TestRecordSource|
    +-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------+----------------+
    only showing top 20 rows

dff:org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
DrgCode:string
LoadDate:timestamp
DrgKey:string
LoadProcess:string
RecordSource:string
```

Comment: was the error you got any different when you used `withColumn("LoadDate",current_timestamp())`

Comment: @big_mike_boiii  Just ran it with that code and: SqlNativeBufferBufferBulkCopy.WriteTdsDataToServer, error in OdbcDone: SqlState: 42000, NativeError: 4816, 'Error calling: bcp_done(this->GetHdbc()) | SQL Error Info: SrvrMsgState: 1, SrvrSeverity: 16,  Error <1>: ErrorMsg: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column type from bcp client for colid 2. | Error calling: pConn->Done() | state: FFFF, number: 91858, active connections: 5', ...

Comment: what happens when you force the `withColumn("LoadDate",current_date())`

Comment: Same error as before  :(

Comment: I wonder if you forced it in to a java.sql.Date if it would handle it

Comment: Even when changing the code to withColumn("LoadDate",to_timestamp(col("LoadDate"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").cast(DateType)) to make it a Date type, it still fails

Comment: I think its a bug in the bulk loader...this code using standard JDBC allows the datetime (timestamp) value to be inserted into that table with no problem: dff.write
 .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")
 .option("url", sqlDwUrlSmall)
  .option("forwardSparkAzureStorageCredentials", "true")
  .option("dbTable", "raw.HubDrg_TEST")
  .option("tempDir", tempDir)
  .mode("append")
  .save()

Comment: I'm not sure, it it may have something to do with the current limitation of the bulk insert API, i.e. some data types are not supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/use-bulk-copy-api-batch-insert-operation?view=sql-server-ver15#known-limitations

Comment: @DimitriB You are correct. According to the link you posted "Due to the limitations of Bulk Copy API, MONEY, SMALLMONEY, DATE, DATETIME, DATETIMEOFFSET, SMALLDATETIME, TIME, GEOMETRY, and GEOGRAPHY data types, are currently not supported for this feature."